# LISP Append Method

Tags: scheme, append, racket

I have to create a procedure called (list-push-front lst new-list) that adds the elements from new-list to the front of lst.  For example, the  output for : (list-push-front '(4 3 7 1 2 9) '( 1 2)) should   give
'(1 2 4 3 7 1 2 9)

This what I have so far but I receive an arity error message for the expected number of arguments(2) not matching the given number expected (1)

```html
 (define(list-push-front lst new-list)   
  (if(null? lst) 
  '()
  (append(list-push-front(car new-list))(lst(car lst)))))
```

Comment: What's wrong with just `(append new-list lst)` ?

Comment: You only give `list-push-front` one argument here: `(list-push-front(car new-list))`. You also try to apply `lst` as a function here: `(lst(car lst))`. If you're using DrRacket, it can highlight parantheses in "levels" to help you see the structure of the code.

Answer (score 3):

Just call the `append` procedure, it does exactly what you need - when using a new procedure you should always refer to the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._append%29%29). In this case we don't have to write an explicit recursion, using the built-in function is enough:

```
(define (list-push-front lst new-list)
  (append new-list lst))
```

For example:

```
(list-push-front '(4 3 7 1 2 9) '(1 2))
=> '(1 2 4 3 7 1 2 9)
```